# Why is the destructor called when the object is passed by reference?

Tags: c++

I pass an Image object to my hash table with the method `insert()`.

```
htImages.insert(WALL_UP_CLOSE, imgWalls[WALL_UP_CLOSE]);
```

As you can see, I'm passing the object into Value by reference.

```
void insert(const Key &key, const Value &value)
{
    Entry entry;
    int index;

    // Build up entry structure
    entry.m_key = key;
    entry.m_value = value;

    // Build the insertion index
    index = m_hash(key) % m_size;

    // Insert the value
    m_table[index].append(entry);

    m_count++;
}
```

However, once this function ends at the last line, the destructor below is being called.

```
Image::~Image()
{
    glDeleteTextures(1, &m_handle);
    refCount--;
}
```

My preference is that the destructor is not called. I'm passing it by reference, so why is the destructor being called?

Comment: **How** are you passing it? Show us the code. All the relevant code, in fact.

Comment: How is `Image` related to the first code sample?

Comment: Show the definition of `Entry`, the type of `m_table`, and the code calling this function.

Comment: You are creating `Key` and `Value` subobjects together with `entry`

Comment: Hmm, that's one out of the three things I listed that we need to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a local variable of type `Entry`, which is automatically destroyed at the end of the function.

When it is destroyed, destructors run for each of its subobjects.

Probably `entry.m_value = value;` is copying something, and the extra copy needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: Thanks for spotting this simple issue out. Giving Entry a static modifier solved the issue.

Comment: @Phil: I somehow doubt that really fixes it.  As I already said, `entry.m_value = value;` looks like a copy assignment operator.  Where does that copy go?